# Linux всегда пингует 10.0.0.1

Tags: linux, сеть, elementary-os

Linux Elementary после запуска всегда обращается к 10.0.0.1, которого не существует.Интернет и сервисы также не работают т.к. всё обращается к 10.0.0.1.
В моей локальной сети также нигде не используется подсеть 10.0.0.*.

При пинге любого сайта, сразу обращается к 10.0.0.1.
PING mail.ru (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

Проблема решается выключение и включение проводного соединения через графический интерфейс, но после перезагрузки снова проблема возникает.

В ifconfig только мои локальный адреса 192.168.*.*
Есть там какой-то интерфейс virbr0 192.168.*.*, не помню, что там и зачем, но он был еще до этой проблемы.

**ip a**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a1:23:01:12:46:fe brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.41/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe21::831a:tr52:11e5:988e/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:55:00:11:er:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.123.1/24 brd 192.168.123.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:55:00:11:er:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**ip r**

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1 proto static metric 20100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.41 metric 100 
192.168.123.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.123.1 linkdown
```

**ip ru**

```
0:  from all lookup local 
220:    from all lookup 220 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   PC
```

***/etc/resolv.conf***

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

***/etc/nsswitch.conf***

```
passwd:         compat systemd
group:          compat systemd
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

***Роутер MikroTik***

Comment: приложите к тексту вопроса вывод `$ ip a; ip r; ip ru; head -n 50 /etc/hosts /etc/resolv.conf /etc/nsswitch.conf` (на всякий случай уточняю: текстом, не картинкой. а то мало ли).

Comment: А какой у вас роутер?

Comment: Приложил к выводу. Роутер MikroTik.

Comment: а если в `/etc/resolv.conf` адрес заменить на какой-нибудь публичный nameserver? например, `8.8.8.8`

Comment: Не помогло. Даже ping на 8.8.8.8 не идёт.

Comment: посмотреть, через что пойдут пакеты можно, например, так: `$ ip r g 8.8.8.8` // да, кстати: а что это у вашего умолчального маршрута метрика с таким запредельно низким приоритетом (чем меньше метрика, тем выше приоритет)? уберите её вообще из этого маршрута.

Comment: а кто сеть поднимает? NM или классика? в первом случае смотри его настройки (через гуйню или ещё-что), а во втором — `/etc/network/interfaces` (если бубунта со времён дебиана ничего не поменяла)... можешь также просто `grep`'нуть `/etc` на предмет адреса `10.0.0`....